# should the destructor be called with placement new even on the same type

Tags: c++, placement-new

```
#include <new>

struct X
{
    ~X() { std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl; }
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, const char * const * const argv)
{
    X x{1};

    new (&x) X{2};

    std::cout << x.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2
destroyed
```

What I know is that the destructor should always be called when placement new is used. However in this sample code, the destructor is implicitly called in the end of the main so calling it again is undefined behaviour I suppose.
so now I want to know if the destructor should always be called when placement new is used or are there certain conditions under which the destructor should not be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's specified explicitly in the C++ standard

> **[basic.life]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#5) A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the
>   storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the
>   destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial
>   destructor. For an object of a class type with a non-trivial
>   destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor
>   explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or
>   released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or
>   if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, the
>   destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends
>   on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

The last sentence leaves a little bit of wriggle room regarding the possibility of undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>. But ultimately, the only types for which this is well-defined are those for which the destructor is truly trivial.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - As of writing this, anyway.</sub>

Comment: that implies that one should preferably always call the dtor before reusing storage of a type with a non trivial dtor in order to guarantee the side effects of that dtor. However, upon scope exit is there still one implicit dtor call guaranteed, is an explicit call a UB then?

Comment: The part about UB will probably be removed. See https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2342

Comment: so this means that one should **not** make the explicit call upon scope exit at the moment right? it is guaranteed to be called then.

Comment: @mkmostafa - One object declared, one object destroyed at scope exit.

Answer (score 2):

> What I know is that the destructor should always be called when placement new is used.

Yes, except when the type is trivially destructible.

In this case, you must destroy the previously constructed object **before** placement new:

```
X x{1};
x.~X();
try {
    new (&x) X{2};
} catch(...) {
    std::abort(); // no way to recover
}
```

An automatic variable of non-trivially destructible type must not go out of scope in a destroyed state. If the constructor throws, the behaviour will be undefined. Reusing memory of a non-trivial object is not recommended.

It is safer to reuse memory of a trivial object:

```
alignas(alignof(X)) std::byte arr[sizeof(X)];
new (arr) X{2};
x.~X();
```

Comment: Note that we have [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) for this purpose. Or, I prefer [`std::aligned_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union), since then you don't need to write all those `sizeof` and `alignof` operators. (It would be nice to simply write `std::aligned_storage_t<X> buf;`, wouldn't it? ;-)